# How to execute one Terraform module in main.tf

Tags: azure, module, terraform

I use Terraform modules in my main.tf file. different module refers to the different resource, an example is shown below:

```
module "cci-api" {
  source   = "../../modules/app-service-general"
  suffix   = var.suffix
  location = var.location
}

module "fmc-api" {
  source   = "../../modules/app-service-fmc"
  suffix   = var.suffix
  location = var.location
}
```

How can I only run the **cci-api** module? Or in another words how can I only deploy the **cci-api** in the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-target` flag for plan/apply, check more information about that [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/plan.html#resource-targeting).  In your case it will be:

```
terraform apply -target="module.cci-api"
```